# MySQL: Only output some values once

Tags: select, mysql

I think I have done this before, but it could also be a function of PHP. What I would like is to do a MySQL query (in a MySQL client, not PHP) and get for example

```
Foo    A
       B
       C
Bar    B
       D
       E
```

Instead of

```
Foo    A
Foo    B
Foo    C
Bar    B
Bar    D
Bar    E
```

This would of course only make sence if it was ordered by that first column. Not sure if it is possible, but like I said, I mean to remember to have done this once, but can't remember how or if it was through some PHP "magic"...

---

**Update:** Suddenly remembered where I had used it. What i was thinking of was the `WITH ROLLUP` modifier for `GROUP BY`. *But* I also discovered that it doesn't do what I was thinking here, so my question still stands. Although I don't think there is a solution now. But smart people have proved me wrong before :P

---

**Update:** Should probably also have mentioned that what I want this for is a many-to-many relationship. In the actual select Foo would be the first name of an attendee and I would also want last name and some other columns. The A, B, C, D, E are options the attendee has selected.

```
attendee (id, first_name, last_name, ...)
attendees_options (attendee_id, option_id)
option (id, name, description)
```

Comment: What's acceptable - NULL, zero length string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you

```
Foo    A,B,C
Bar    B,D,E    

SELECT column1, GROUP_CONCAT(column2) FROM table GROUP BY column1
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know about the `group_concat` statement. Even supports multiple columns, ordering and custom separator... Might end up using this...

Answer (score 0):

Tested this in SQL Server, but I think it will translate to MySQL.

```
create table test (
    id int,
    col1 char(3),
    col2 char(1)
)

insert into test
    (id, col1, col2)
    select 1, 'Foo', 'A' union all
    select 2, 'Foo', 'B' union all
    select 3, 'Foo', 'C' union all
    select 4, 'Bar', 'D' union all
    select 5, 'Bar', 'E' union all
    select 6, 'Bar', 'F'

select case when t.id = (select top 1 t2.id 
                             from test t2 
                             where t2.col1 = t.col1 
                             order by t2.col1, t2.col2) 
            then t.col1
            else ''
       end as col1, 
       t.col2
    from test t
    order by t.id

drop table test
```

Comment: Needed some adjustments, but actually worked for this example. Guess it would require one of those big `case` blocks for each column that might be duplicated though...?